# Does Google Maps API v2 Android support offline maps?

Tags: android, api, google-maps, offline

I'm trying to understand what i'm asking for...
I googled around with no success (of course, starting from official google developer site).

The result i would like achieve is the same behavior official Maps app from Google has, choosing to "make available offline" a part of the map and saving a selected area.

Does anyone know how to do it (if possible)? Can you point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The Maps V2 API, at this time, does not give us any ability to control offline maps.

Comment: This would be a good reason to find nothing about on Google Developer.